# How to append a string with all lines in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have multiple text files opened in Notepad++. And each file is like this.

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

And I want to append a string like this in all opened files, like this.

```
string line1
string line2
string line3
string line4
```

How to do this?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1003790/how-to-find-and-replace-lines-in-multiple-files-using-notepad

Answer (score 2):

In `Replace` window, do the following:

1. Select the tab `Find in Files`
2. In `Find what:` type `^`
3. In `Replace with:` type `string`
4. Select radio button `Regular expression`

Comment: This would not even be an exact answer for a single file, but the OP also wants to do this for multiple open files.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : If I understood the question correctly then, OP wants to prepend a string to every line of already opened files as shown in OP's example.

Comment: There is a space between the prepended string and the original line if I read correctly.

Answer (score 0):

press Alt + Left click down, select your lines and left click up.

Comment: works fine for a file, but what about multiple opened files, is it possible to do with all files with a single operation?